# Meteor/React Router 4 - Homepage and connected user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

Another post to ask you about a "situation" I am having, which is disappointing as my Router is creating too many refreshs and for the point is actually not to have to refresh part of the page by using React.

I would like the following :

When I go to './' and there is no user connected it shows a homepage (without header and footer)
When I go to './' and I am connected or any other link whether I am connected ot not it should show the relevant page with a Header and a Footer.

So the fact of  being not connected does not show header/footer is only true for the './' address.

How I solved it and it is not satisfying because it seems my header is rerendering all the time I change pages even between two pages with Router....

I have a first Router, the AppRouter :

```
 const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="content">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true} />
                <SubRouter />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

My index is like that :

```
export class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (this.props.user){
            return (
                <SubRouter />
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Homepage />
            )   
        }
    }
}
```

So if no user the Homepage is showing if user it goes back to the SubRouter.

SubRouter is like that :

```
export class SubRouter extends React.Component {
    (...)
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="fullpage">
            {this.state.inboxOpen ? <Inbox closeInbox={this.closeInbox} oneUserInboxId={this.state.oneUserInboxId} /> : undefined }
                <Header openInbox={this.openInbox} closeInbox={this.closeInbox} />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/account" component={Account} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/faq" component={Faq} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/cgv" component={Cgv} exact={true}/>
                    <Route path="/legal" component={Legal} exact={true}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} exact={true}/>
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} exact={true}/>
                    <Route path="/notifications" render={() => (<Dashboard notifications={true} />)} exact={true} />
                    }} />
                    <Route path="/reset-password/:token" component={ResetPassword} />
                    <Route path="/forgot_password" component={ForgotPassword} exact={true} />
                    <Route path="/post/:postId" component={OnePost} />
                    <Route path="/*" component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So this code is "working" but somehow we can see rerenders that should not happen, I am open to any idea to optimize this. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was coming from here :

```
 const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="content">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true} />
                <SubRouter />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Should not have rerendered SubRouter here as it is already rendered in HomePage. Good code is :

```
 const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="content">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={Index} exact={true} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```